# java jsonxpth parsing json jumping to node

Tags: java, json, parsing, jxpath

I have the following data and i am using "http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/" i want to directly read the coordinates: [51.464426 -0.382974] which is lat,lng how can i read this any quick example i search around and found there is another jsonpath as well is jsonxpath going to work for me any quick solution ?

```
{

    authenticationResultCode: "ValidCredentials"
    brandLogoUri: http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png
    copyright: "Copyright © 2011 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation."
    -
    resourceSets: [
        -
        {
            estimatedTotal: 1
            -
            resources: [
                -
                {
                    __type: "Location:http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1"
                    -
                    bbox: [
                        51.46056328242933
                        -0.39124021297987016
                        51.46828871757068
                        -0.3747077870201298
                    ]
                    name: "TW4 5AP, Hounslow, United Kingdom"
                    -
                    point: {
                        type: "Point"
                        -
                        coordinates: [
                            51.464426
                            -0.382974
                        ]
                    }
                    -
                    address: {
                        adminDistrict: "England"
                        adminDistrict2: "Hounslow"
                        countryRegion: "United Kingdom"
                        formattedAddress: "TW4 5AP, Hounslow, United Kingdom"
                        postalCode: "TW4 5AP"
                    }
                    confidence: "High"
                    entityType: "Postcode1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    statusCode: 200
    statusDescription: "OK"
    traceId: "16c9b05027c4486fa3adab793cfdb97e|EWRM001665|02.00.82.2800|EWRMSNVM001812, EWRMSNVM001724"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath/tree/master/json-path or http://code.google.com/p/json-path/. I dont